# Ansible run 'composer install' with GitHub OAuth token

Tags: ansible, composer-php, devops, ansible-2.x

I try to make an Ansible deployment script for my web server. It should run 'composer install'. In my composer JSON are some private GitHub repos. Anyone knows how to add a GitHub OAuth token to an Ansible playbook? Or know a workaround? The 'github_oauth: {{ token }}' below is like how I dream of getting it to work.

```
    - name: "Run composer install"
       become: yes
       become_user: username
       composer:
         command: install
         github_oauth: {{ token }}
         global_command: false
         working_dir: /home/username/web/domain.com/public_html
```

Comment: Ansible is about automating existing processes; so how do you auth your composer install when not using ansible?

Comment: I usually store the auth credentials in the composer global auth.json. So, running a command before composer install to add the token is the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going the classic way and adding the OAuth key to the global composer config before the run composer install task is working:

```
- name: "Composer add github oauth for {{ user }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ user }}'
  composer:
    command: config
    arguments: github-oauth.github.com {{ gh_oauth_token }}
    global_command: true
```

If someone knows a one task solution, please let me know. Otherwise, this solves the problem.